# Realtime barcode detections with Google Mobile Vision

Tags: java, android, barcode

I am using this Camerakit (https://github.com/natario1/CameraView/) and using its Frame Processor for realtime barcode detection with Google Mobile Vision. Here is the code

```
cameraView.addFrameProcessor(new FrameProcessor() {
 @Override
 @WorkerThread
 public void process(@NonNull com.otaliastudios.cameraview.Frame frame) {
  byte[] data = frame.getData();
  Frame myFrame = new Frame.Builder()
   .setImageData(ByteBuffer.wrap(data), 640, 480, ImageFormat.NV21)
   .build();
  BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector =
   new BarcodeDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext())
   .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.ALL_FORMATS)
   .build();
  SparseArray < Barcode > barcodes = barcodeDetector.detect(myFrame);
  if (barcodes.size() != 0) {

   final Barcode thisCode = barcodes.valueAt(0);

   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
     textViewResult.setText(thisCode.rawValue);
    }
   });


  }
 }
});
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here! Need help :)
Thanks.